# Azure Devops CI pipeline failing when adding SonarQube

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to add SonarQube into a CI pipeline on Azure DevOps.

My project is .Net Core 2.2 application. The error is related to Agent JDK. I don't know how can I specify the JDK of Microsoft Hosted Agent.

All the tutorials of SonarQube and .NET core pipelines are the same, but none mentioned anything about this issue.

Here's a snapshot about how my pipeline looks like:

[image]

Here's the error that's always happening with me. Shouldn't Microsoft Hosted Agent know what `capabilities` to use by its own?

Anyone have an idea about how we can solve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the JDK used in Micorosft Hosted Machine, for some reason the JDK used was not the supposed one.
The solution was following these steps:

1. Uploading a JDK `zip`file to Azure blob storage
2. Running Java Tool Installer in my Pipeline, giving it the Uploaded `zip` file as resource
3. Run Code Analysis successfully finished then and results was published to my SonarQube server

Here's how my pipeline looks like right now:

[image]